# Seeking explanation of how shifting bits can verify the sign of a number

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have this excerpt from geeksforgeeks, assume x and y are integers.

“If (x-y) is smaller than 0, then (x -y)>>31 will be 1. If (x-y) is greater than or equal to 0, then (x -y)>>31 will be 0.”

I’m curious to know why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case for signed 32-bit integers in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form.

The sign-bit is the most significant bit. The shift operation `>>31` will shift the sign-bit to the least significant bit position. A `1` indicates, that the difference is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The quote is assuming a 32-bit two's complement representation of integers (this is the most common representation of integers, though using 64 bits is becoming more common). In particular, of the 32 bits used to represent an integer, the highest order bit is used to represent whether the integer is negative or positive. Highest bit = 1 means negative, highest bit = 0 means non-negative. Thus, if you compute (x-y) and the 32nd bit tells you whether x >= y (32nd bit = 0) or x < y (32nd bit = 1). So how do you get the 32nd bit? Shift right 31 times.